# Javadoc comments in IntelliJ for haxe are a mess

Tags: intellij-idea, comments, javadoc, haxe

IntelliJ14's javadoc-style autoformatting for haxe is driving me up the wall. Anyone figure out how to turn off this 'feature'? Here's what happens (I've confirmed this happens for other people too)...

[image: Terrible auto-formatting in IntelliJ]

Comment: I've got exactly same issue :/ My guess is it's Haxe plugin's fault. Unfortunately I didn't figure out how to fix it.
(Btw, "quick doc" preview also looks ugly)

Comment: Wld love to have the time/brains to fix this. There are plenty of other little nigglers. E.g. double-click selection in comments or strings selects a whole sentence rather than a word. Who ever selects by sentence?!